# Products Query from Quickbooks Online

Tags: php, sql, quickbooks

I was working on Quickbooks API with PHP and I was trying to get data from QuickBooks and storing in MySql. I got customers and vendor working. But I cannot get Product working.

Does anyone know what the product table is called in Quickbooks.

For Customers:

```
Select * From customer --worked
```

For Vendors:

```
Select * From vedor --worked
```

For Products I was trying:

```
Select * From product --Didn't work
```

Does anyone know what query would be to return products from Quickbooks.?

Comment: Maybe read the Quickbooks docs?

Comment: I found a third party doc that lists the tables. There is no product table. http://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/usa/TableList.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link mkaatman provided, it looks like products are called items. Try this.

```
 Select * From item
```